# Why is my use of Operator[] on std::map invalid?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a map with type

```
std::map<int, Node> G;
```

Node is as follows

```
struct Node{
  Node(){};
  int data;
};
```

I want to use operator[] to return a reference to a Node if it is in the map, or create a new one and return a reference if it is not.  That is my understanding of what the documentation says:

> If k matches the key of an element in the container, the function returns a reference to its mapped value.
>
> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor).

However, the following code throws an error (g++ 5, std=gnu++11):

> error: cannot convert ‘std::map::mapped_type {aka Node}’ to ‘Node*’ in assignment u_ptr = G[3];

```
Node* u_ptr;
u_ptr = G[3];
```

In all the examples I've seen, `G[k]` appears on the lhs.  Is `G[k]` not allowed on a rhs?  If not, why?

Comment: Look up *pointers* in your course book.

Comment: Your'e assigning to a pointer to `Node`, but the map contains `Node`s. This is no different from `Node a; Node* b = a;`.

Comment: Did you mean `u_ptr = &G[3];`

Comment: I have been reading "reference" as a synonym for "pointer"... :S  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map<Key, T>::operator[]` returns a `T&` reference.

In this case, `T` is `Node`, so `G[3]` returns a `Node&` reference, which you are then trying to assign to a `Node*` pointer.  That is why you are getting a compiler error.

So, you can either:

1. change `u_ptr` to a reference:

   ```
   Node& u_ptr = G[3];
   ```
2. use the `&` address operator to convert the reference into a pointer:

   ```
   Node* u_ptr;
   u_ptr = &G[3];
   ```

Comment: Also worth mentioning `auto& u_ptr = G[3];`

Comment: Ahh, very dumb mistake...  I have been reading "reference" as a synonym for "pointer".

Comment: @RJTK: In the compiled machine code, a reference and a pointer will usually generate the same code. But semantically, they are treated as different types in the language.